# how to check if variable exists in sql table if not exists then condition and insert it into table in anylogic

Tags: java, anylogic

In anylogic code section I am adding this code to chech whether values exist in external database(Microsoft sql server), But getting error that can not find vanet.vehicle

```
selectFrom(vanet).
      where(vanet.vehicle.eq(vehicle.getIndex())).
      firstResult( vanet.surrounded );

if (vanet.surrounded==null)
  {      
        System.out.println("surr :" + vanet.surrounded);

        insertInto(vanet)
    .columns(vanet.vehicle, vanet.surrounded)
    .values(vehicle.getIndex(), v.getIndex())
    .execute();
     k =1;
        }
else {
 k=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not accessing a SQL dbase but the AnyLogic build-in database. If it says it cannot find `vanet.vehicle` that means there is either no table named `vanet` in the build-in dbase or there is but no column named `vehicle`.

Make sure you know to either use the build-in dbase (my recommendation) or connect correctly to an external SQL db (but then you cannot use the code above as it accesses the AL db)